# the follow button on the itemView is not working properly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I use `RecyclerView` for searching for users.
the search works fine, but the follow button in the `ItemView` is not.

Whenever I press the follow button, the text on the button is supposed to change from "follow" to "following". and and when I press it again it supposed to change from "following" to "follow". it was working just fine and suddenly it just stopped working!

Whenever I press the button it changes from "follow" to "following" for a sec and then it return to "follow". I couldn't figure out the reason!

Here is my code.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

 final User user = mUsers.get(position);
 isFollowing(user.getId(), holder.btn_follow);
 holder.btn_follow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.btn_follow.getText().toString().equals("follow"))
                {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child("following").child(user.getId()).setValue(true);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getId())
                            .child("followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                    addNotifications(user.getId());
                }
                else
                {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child("following").child(user.getId()).removeValue();
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getId())
                            .child("followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                   // FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(user.getId()).removeValue();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the isFollowing function:

```
private void isFollowing(final String userid, final Button button) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("following");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(userid).exists()) {
                    button.setText("following");
                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonafter);
                } else {
                    button.setText("follow");
                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonbefore);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

It keeps returning to the default "follow" text on the button, so it is not allowing me to follow anyone.

Please help if you know what's causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Move your implementation of `onClickListener()` of your button from `onBindViewHolder()` method to your `ViewHolder` class of your `RecyclerView`. It's not a good idea to implement listeners in `onBindViewHolder()`.

Comment: I tried to do so but as you can see I have this  final User user = mUsers.get(position); inside onBindViewHolder() method. so when I move the onClickListener() to ViewHolder method, the variable (user) becomes red and I could not fix it